# Issues with allignment on print preview for html page

Tags: html, css, printing, preview

I have developed a html page
But whenever I do a print preview all my contents are getting disloacated.

I am dam sure that I made something wrong at my css giving size ,height,width..

But not sure where exactly its going wrong.
Is there any alternative ,so it will not affect my existing css.
I have heard about media tag...do you people have any example for the same.

Comment: share ur piece of code

Comment: Could you provide us with the code please?

Comment: Using media queries you can target different screens. You can have a look at the mediq queries here [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and here [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom CSS for printing:
Option 1:
Append media print property to your css stylesheet link

```
    <link href="/css/style.css" media="screen,print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">                               
                                               ^^^
```

And then you can write custom css for printing in this stylesheet

```
@media print {
    div {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Option 2:
You can add whole css file for only printing.

```
        <link href="/css/style.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

In this case is not necessary to use `@media print {` in this stylesheet

Comment: Actually I am adding my contents dynamically by javascript. this is what creating an issue. As when I copied my html code and save it in different one it showed same alignment issue.